# How can I set MessageHeader when creating a rule?

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I create a rule from text in an input file.

One of the rule conditions is to examine the message header of a received email and move the email based on the message header content.

I tried the .TEXT property to no avail.
I googled but nothing comes up.

I have over 300 rules, many of which require the message header test.

I get the same error when assigning a text string to `oRule.Conditions.Subject.Text`.

> "Run time error '13' - Type mismatch"

I tried String and Variant for the fields, I get the same message.

```vb
Dim strMessageHeader As Variant

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, StrRuleName, strCond, strFrom, strSubject, strSentTo, strMessageHeader, strSendersAddress, strMoveTo, strSetCategory
    ' Create the rule
    Set oRule = colRules.Create(StrRuleName, olRuleReceive)
            
    ' What is the condition?
    Select Case strCond
    Case olConditionFrom            ' 1 - Condition is "from"
        Set oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From
        With oFromCondition
            .Enabled = True
            .Recipients.Add (strFrom)
            .Recipients.ResolveAll
        End With
    Case olConditionSubject         ' 2 - Condition is text "in the subject"
        Set oSubjectCondition = oRule.Conditions.Subject
        With oSubjectCondition
            .Enabled = True
            .Text = strSubject
        End With
    Case olConditionSentTo          ' 12 - Condition is "sent to a specific email"
        Set oSentToCond = oRule.Conditions.SentTo
        With oSentToCond
            .Enabled = True
            .Recipients.Add (strSentTo)
        End With
    Case olConditionMessageHeader   ' 15 - Condition is text "in the message header"
        Set oMsgHdrCond = oRule.Conditions.MessageHeader
        With oMsgHdrCond
            .Text = strMessageHeader
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Rule.Conditions.MessageHeader.Text` property.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I do that per
            Set oMsgHdrCond = oRule.Conditions.MessageHeader
            With oMsgHdrCond
                
                .Text = strMessageHeader
            End With
But I get an error message indicating a Run time error 13, Type Mismatch

Comment: What is the value and type of the strMessageHeader variable?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out - the .text needs to be assigned using a text array not a text string or variant.
I used the following that worked:

```
        Case olConditionMessageHeader   ' 15 - Condition is text "in the message header"
            Set oMsgHdrCond = oRule.Conditions.MessageHeader
            With oMsgHdrCond
                .Enabled = True
                .Text = Array(strMessageHeader)
            End With)
```